# std::function template argument deduction for member attributes

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

With this small example, I'm trying to get the compiler to automatically deduce the template argument for the 2nd parameter. This works but is not as succinct as I would like.

```
struct Student {
    AgeCategory age;
    Income income;
    bool is_student;
    CreditRating credit_rating;
    bool buys_computer;
};


// This works  (A)
template<typename R>
auto calc_mean(const std::vector<Student> & in, std::function<R (Student const&)> attr)-> double
{
    const auto mean = std::accumulate(std::begin(in), std::end(in), 0.0, [&attr](auto acc, const auto& val) {
        // Call the attribute passed in
        return acc += static_cast<double>(attr(val));
    }) / static_cast<double>(in.size());
    return mean;
}

// This doesn't work (B)
template<typename T>
auto calc_mean(const std::vector<Student> & in, T attr)-> double
{
    const auto mean = std::accumulate(std::begin(in), std::end(in), 0.0, [&attr](auto acc, const auto& val) {
    // Call the attribute passed in
    return acc += static_cast<double>(attr(val));
}) / static_cast<double>(in.size());
  return mean;
}

// Caller (A) - works but I have to explicitly state the attribute type
mean_stddev<AgeCategory>(buy, &Student::age);
// Caller (B) - what I'd like to be able to do and let compiler infer types
mean_stddev(buy, &Student::age);
```

Error is

```
>..\src\Main.cpp(16): error C2672: mean_stddev': no matching overloaded function found
1>..\src\Main.cpp(16): error C2784: 'std::tuple<double,double> mean_stddev(const std::vector<Student,std::allocator<_Ty>> &,T *)': could not deduce template argument for 'T *' from AgeCategory Student::* '
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Student
1>          ]
1>  c:\users\chowron\documents\development\projects\ml\src\Bayes.h(25): note: see declaration of mean_stddev'
```

What do I have to do to the function declaration for B to work with the more concise syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To invoke `attr`, you need to use [`std::invoke`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke):

```
template <class R> // <-- NB: R, not T
double calc_mean(const std::vector<Student>& in, R attr)
{
    const auto mean = std::accumulate(in.begin(), in.end(), 0.0, [&attr](auto acc, const auto& val) {
        return acc + static_cast<double>(std::invoke(attr, val));
    }) / static_cast<double>(in.size());
    return mean;
}
```

Or honestly:

```
template <class R> // <-- NB: R, not T
double calc_mean(const std::vector<Student>& in, R attr)
{
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (auto const& s : in) {
        sum += std::invoke(attr, s);
    }
    return sum / in.size();
}
```

`invoke()` is a C++17 function template, but you can implement it in C++11 per the reference attached. It will do the right thing for both functions, function objects, and pointers to members - which is basically what you want.

Comment: I didn't know about invoke. Appears to work in MSVC15 too. Thanks

Comment: The C++11 kludge is `std::ref(attr)(s)`.

Comment: @T.C. That just makes me sad. I need to rewrite my pointers-to-members proposal and resubmit it. I really just want to write `attr(s)`.

Answer (score 0):

> What do I have to do to the function declaration for B to work with the more concise syntax.

First of all, you should use the same template identificator: or `R` or `T`

```
template<typename T>  // <--- use R here
auto calc_mean(const std::vector<Student> & in, R attr)-> double
{
    const auto mean = std::accumulate(std::begin(in), std::end(in), 0.0, [&attr](auto acc, const auto& val) {
    // Call the attribute passed in
    return acc += static_cast<double>(attr(val));
}) / static_cast<double>(in.size());
  return mean;
}
```